# Display foreach in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a sourcecode like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['text_boxx'])) { 
        $aa = $_POST['text_boxx'];
        $myFilee = "./SCENARIO/ocstesting-aktif.txt";
        $fhh = fopen($myFilee, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fhh,$aa);
        fclose($fhh); 
        }    

        if(isset($myFilee)){
        $myFilee2 = "./SCENARIO/ocstesting.txt";
        $fhh2 = fopen($myFilee2, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        $filer = file('./SCENARIO/ocstesting-aktif.txt'); 


        foreach ($filer as $file_num => $fileline){
        $aaa="{$file_num}. Hello my name is: " . $fileline . " hoho \n";
        fwrite($fhh2,$aaa); 
        }       
        fclose($fhh2);
        }
?>
```

if I input in textbox :

```
Oki 
Dito
```

I want it appears in web like :

```
0. Hello my name is Oki hoho
1. Hello my name is Dito hoho
```

but it appears :

```
 0. Hello my name is: Oki 
hoho 
1. Hello my name is: Dito hoho
```

Please anyone can help :( ? Thank You

Comment: Your concern is about spacing & alignment issues?

Comment: question is: *How* are you displaying that? Your post doesn't support the problem. It's missing a lot of things; the form and the method of file retrieval and displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File function return an array with the line ending : see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php#refsect1-function.file-returnvalues)

2 solutions :

- use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag
- use `rtrim` in your `$fileline`

Answer (score 0):

you should to write this line as following

```
$aaa="{$file_num}. Hello my name is " . $fileline . " hoho \n";
```

Just omit the : after is.

Comment: And how to remove a line break?

Comment: you can write $fileline like that trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $fileline));